# Why my canvas getImageData doesn't work?

Tags: html, image, canvas, colors, pixel

I am trying to pick up a color from a image pixel with that simple code :

```
<body>
    <img src="image.png" id="monImage"/>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var img = $('#monImage')[0];
            var canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0];
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

            var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1);

            alert("test");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I am using jquery so it's easier to select element. If I comment this line :

```
var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Then the `alert()` works and apears on my screen. But if I don't comment it doesn't, so that line doesn't works. Why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

At the point your function executes the image is not done loading (image data is not available).

The image *element* is valid however so you can read its properties. This is why it doesn't fail before, but its `width` and `height` properties will be 0.

A little bitsurprising is that you can execute the line with `drawImage`. However at the point you get to `getImageData` there is no data to retrieve and therefor it will fail.

You need to either put your code inside a window `load` event handler or add an event listener to the image element.

For example:

```
window.onload = function() {

    /// your function goes here

}
```